# bootstrap modal window not working in the latest version of bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am creating an angular 7 application with bootstrap 4. The moment  I have upgraded to bootstrap 4 , the modal windows have stopped working.
Could somebody tell me what the problem is

We have been using wrapper called bs-modal like below

```
 <bs-modal #firmmodal [keyboard]="false" [backdrop]="'static'">
            <bs-modal-header>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Firm - {{ManagerStrategyDetails.FirmName}}
                    <div style="text-align: right"><button aria-label="Dismiss" class="close" style="margin-top: -20px" type="button" (click)="dismissFirmModal()">X</button></div>
                </h4>
            </bs-modal-header>
            <bs-modal-body>
                <mgr-firm></mgr-firm>
            </bs-modal-body>
            <bs-modal-footer [showDefaultButtons]="false"></bs-modal-footer>
        </bs-modal>

        <bs-modal #managermodal [keyboard]="false" [backdrop]="'static'">
            <bs-modal-header>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Manager - {{ManagerStrategyDetails.ManagerName}}
                    <div style="text-align: right"><button aria-label="Dismiss" class="close" style="margin-top: -20px" type="button" (click)="dismissManagerModal()">X</button></div>
                </h4>
            </bs-modal-header>
            <bs-modal-body>
                <mgr-manager [ManagerId] = 'ManagerId' ></mgr-manager>
            </bs-modal-body>
            <bs-modal-footer [showDefaultButtons]="false"></bs-modal-footer>
        </bs-modal>
```

Component

```
import { BsModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';
    openFirmModal() {
            this.firmmodal.open();
        }

        dismissFirmModal() {
            this.firmmodal.dismiss();
        }

          openFundModal() {
                this.fundmodal.open();
            }

            dismissFundModal() {

                this.fundmodal.dismiss();
            }
```

Comment: Do you get console errors?

Comment: No errors in console and thats what is making it difficult for me to understand. I have a feeling that ng2-bs3-modal doesnt support bootstrap 4 onwards. If anybody has implemented ng-bootstrap please do let me know.

Comment: try to change this line: "import { BsModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal'; " to import from "ng2-bs4-modal";

Answer (score 0):

There is a related, closed issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal/issues/193

In summary, they mentioned no immediate plans to support bootstrap 4, but suggest trying ng2-bs4-modal. https://github.com/maxfisher05/ng2-bs4-modal